# Unity Framework using configuration

Tags: c#, design-patterns, dependency-injection, unity-container

I have this piece of code in C# using Unity Framework

```
static void MakeEverythingReady(UnityContainer container)
{
        try
        {

            container.RegisterType<ICar, Maruti>("UseMaruti", 
                new InjectionConstructor(new ResolvedParameter<MarutiEngine>()));
            container.Resolve<ICar>("UseMaruti");
            container.RegisterType<IEngine, MarutiEngine>("UseMarutiEngine");
            container.Resolve<IEngine>("UseMarutiEngine");
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(ex.Message);
        }
    }
```

I have tried to do the same thing using configuration and wrote this ....

```
<configuration>
<configSections>
<section name="unity"
        type="Microsoft.Practices.Unity.Configuration.UnityConfigurationSection,
             Microsoft.Practices.Unity.Configuration" />
</configSections>

<startup> 
    <supportedRuntime version="v4.0" sku=".NETFramework,Version=v4.5" />
</startup>

<unity>
<typeAliases>
  <typeAlias alias="singleton"
     type="Microsoft.Practices.Unity.ContainerControlledLifetimeManager,
           Microsoft.Practices.Unity" />
</typeAliases>
<containers>
  <container name="containerCar">
    <type type="UnityCar.IEngine" mapTo="UnityCar.MarutiEngine" name="UseMarutiEngine" />
    <type type="UnityCar.ICar" mapTo="UnityCar.Maruti" name="UseMaruti">
      <typeConfig extensionType="Microsoft.Practices.Unity.Configuration.TypeInjectionElement,
                                 Microsoft.Practices.Unity.Configuration">
        <constructor>
          <param name="UseMarutiEngine" parameterType="UnityCar.IEngine">
            <dependency/>>
          </param>
        </constructor>
      </typeConfig>
    </type>
  </container>
</containers>
</unity>
</configuration>
```

Trying to load this configuration file using following piece of code

```
UnityConfigurationSection section = (UnityConfigurationSection)ConfigurationManager.GetSection("unity");
section.Configure(container, "containerCar");
```

Here we have two assemblies UnityExample is a console and UnityCar is a dll which having all interfaces and concrete implementations. This config file is app.config of UnityExample.

It is throwing configuration exception --

```
Unrecognized element 'typeConfig'
```

Any clue?

Comment: what exception is thrown? please add the information to your question to get a qualified answer

Comment: Your container name ("containerOne") doesn't seem to be defined in the Unity config file (where I see "containerCar"). Might it be the problem?

Comment: Thanks David, good catch, I have tried it by changing it to ContainerCar, still getting this typeConfig error.

Answer (score 0):

I've seen this problem before. Unfortunately, I cannot manage to solve it as I expected.
For me, the solution was removing the typeConfig element from the config.
So I guess, if you modify your app.config to this, It should work:

```
<type type="UnityCar.ICar" mapTo="UnityCar.Maruti" name="UseMaruti">
        <constructor>
          <param name="UseMarutiEngine" parameterType="UnityCar.IEngine">
            <dependency/>>
          </param>
        </constructor>
</type>
```